# UWP send file data to WebView

Tags: c#, webview, uwp, pdf.js, storagefile

I have an app coded in C#, but I would like to show a PDF file in a WebView with pdf.js. The APIs that the UWP provides for viewing PDFs are too limited for me, they do not support things like text selection and it can be very slow with large files.
Is it possible (if so, what would be the best way to) open a file (StorageFile) using pdf.js inside a WebView inside a C# UWP app?

Comment: Have you seen this: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/6535#issuecomment-354782819

Comment: if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible (if so, what would be the best way to) open a file (StorageFile) using pdf.js inside a WebView inside a C# UWP app?

The short answer is yes, and there is already such  [control](https://github.com/xamarin/recipes/tree/master/Recipes/xamarin-forms/Controls/display-pdf), but it only works in `Xamarin.Forms`. You can port it to UWP easily.

**Step 1**

Import [pdfjs](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/getting_started/#download) JavaScript package to your UWP project.

[image]

**Step 2**

Instantiate a WebView control that used to display pdfjs index page.

```
<WebView Name="PDFViewer"/>
```

**Step 3**

Create PDFViewer source that contain pdf file absolute path.

```
PDFViewer.Source = new Uri(string.Format("ms-appx-web:///pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file={0}", string.Format("ms-appx-web:///Assets/{0}", WebUtility.UrlEncode("hello.pdf"))));
```

[image]